# Проверка столкновений с блоком (гравитация)

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

Код на Java Android, вроде все должно нормально работать,но происходит такое: человек падает на 1-ый блок, всё нормально, он останавливается,но когда проходишь чуть дальше игрок падает вниз, помогите,код:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int st = 0;//для цикла
    int bx = 100; //х координата
    int by = 780;//y координата
    x = x + xSpeed; //x равен самому себе плюс скорость по оси x
    y = y - ySpeed;//y равен самому себе минус скорость по y(падение)
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE); //фон
    if ((Math.abs(bx - x) <= (125 + 100) / 2f) &&
        (Math.abs(by - y) <= (125 + 100) / 2f)) {//вокруг персонажа рисуем прямоугольник и узнаем что будет при столкновение
        ySpeed = 0;
        y = y - ySpeed;
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, x, y, null);//рисуем персонажа
    } else {//если персонаж не столкнулся
        ySpeed = -4;
        y = y - ySpeed;
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, x, y, null);
    }
    for (st = 0; st < 14; st++) {//тут запускаем цикл для рисования блоков
        bx = bx + 100;//x координата
        canvas.drawBitmap(dirtes, bx, by, null);//рисуем блок
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете добавить скриншоты, не могу представить себе то что вы хотите сделать

Comment: Щас скину,но вообще я хочу сделать так чтобы допустим игрок в воздухе,он падает, когда он сталкивается с землёй/полом человечек останвливал падение и стоял(прямо как мы, когда прыгаем/падаем мы же не пролетаем сквозь пол)

Comment: Все,добавил, вроде должно быть понятно

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то когда он отходит вправо bx - x по модулю становится больше (225)/2, условие перестает выполнятся и он падает

Comment: Аааа,я понял, всё до боли просто,вы правы